# Lsing API to list results in different method

Tags: c#, json

The aim of the program below is to get a list of Reports built in our database and find out how many of these reports use the field NameFirst within them.

I'm able to make an API call and, at GetReports, get a list of the ReportIDs.

However, I'm unable to move forward with calling the list I created at GetReports in the next method, GetNameFirst. I was wondering if someone could please help me out with this.

For the script below, I get a red underline for the variable values. This is understandable because I didn't know where and how to tell my code to bind the list output for GetReports to the variable values in GetNameFirst.

Also, if I could get some help in finding out which reports have the field NameFirst in them once I accomplish calling the list from the first method to the second, I'd appreciate that also. I'm currently heading in the direction of using a foreach, but I'm unsure if that's the best path to take.

Main Program

```
namespace NameFirstSearch
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        const string username = "Username";
        const string password = "Password";
        const string baseUrl = "https://example.com/rest/services/";
        const string queryString = "query?q=Select * From Report Where LastRanDate is not null";
        const string queryNameFirst = "getreport/";

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", auth);

        GetReports(client, queryString).Wait();
        GetNameFirst(client, queryNameFirst).Wait();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task<List<Properties>> GetReports(HttpClient client, string queryString)
    {
        List<Properties> result = new List<Properties>();

        var response = await client.GetAsync(queryString);

        // Check for a successfull result
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Properties>>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Count());
        }
        else
        {
            // Error code returned
            Console.WriteLine("No records found on first method.");
        }
        return result;
    }

    static async Task GetNameFirst(HttpClient client, string queryNameFirst)
    {
        string reportType = "JSON";

        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            var output = await client.GetAsync(queryNameFirst + item.ReportID + reportType);

            if (output.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var allText = await output.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var fields = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NameFirst>>(allText);
            }
            else
            {
                // Error code returned
                Console.WriteLine("No records found on second method.");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Class for report list

```
class Properties
{
    public int ReportID { get; set; }
}
```

Class for reports' NameFirst property

```
class NameFirst
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: first off, get any ReportID and call the API to getNameFirst (manually). If you ensured that your API calling is a success and the results is also correct, then recheck your work again to see what are you messing. Also, couldn't find the `values` in your foreach loop `foreach (var item in values)` within your provided code.

Comment: @iSR5             Hello, values in foreach(var item in values) should be equal to result [the list of reportIDs]. I may not have been able to understand you well for the first part of your comment, but I don't think I can do what you're suggesting. The reportID is independent to the report itself after it gets called in the second query. What I mean is that the report is not part of the same table as when it is outputted by the second query. Would it help if I added photos of the results of a direct query using MSSMS?

Comment: In VS, use F11 to debug, check the reportId value, make sure you're getting a value and not null when it passes to the GetNameFirst method.

Comment: @iSR5           I don't think we are on the same page here. My question is how do I get the results <result> from GetReports to pass through GetNameFirst. Everything I wrote for GetNameFirst is useless because I can't get the list from GetReports to be properly called at GetNameFirst. I want to basically tell my script result from Method 1 is equal to values in Method 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this was a partial code, but since you've cleared things out.

you'll need to change your code a bit

this :

```
GetReports(client, queryString).Wait();
```

do it like this :

```
var reportsList = GetReports(client, queryString).Result;
```

now, you'll need to pass the `reportsList` to the second method `GetNameFirst` which would be adjusted to this :

```
static async Task GetNameFirst(HttpClient client,  string queryNameFirst, List<Properties> results)
{
    string reportType = "JSON";

    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        var output = await client.GetAsync(queryNameFirst + item.ReportID + reportType);

        if (output.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var allText = await output.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var fields = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NameFirst>>(allText);
        }
        else
        {
            // Error code returned
            Console.WriteLine("No records found on second method.");
        }

    }

}
```

with this adjustment, you'll need to adjust the call as well :

```
GetNameFirst(client, queryNameFirst, reportsList).Wait();
```

Comment: I'm a little confused here. First, I can't replace GetReports(client, queryString).Wait(); with var reportsList = await GetReports(client, queryString); . This edit would occur at main and when I replace one with the other I get an error stating, "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method." This makes sense so removing the keyword 'await' to get var reportsList = GetReports(client, queryString); removes the red underline. Now, to your second suggestion. I am completely lost here. You are telling me to create var reportsList, but it is never being used. Please clarify.

Comment: The reportList should be passed to GetNameFirst. I have updated the answered, I forgot to correct the variable name.

Comment: Got it. I assumed you were recommending that. I'm still getting an error at   var  reportsList = GetReports(client, queryString);
               GetNameFirst(client, queryNameFirst, reportsList).Wait();                     I took a snapshot and updated the question with it.

Comment: @ChunkyFresh fix this line `var reportsList = GetReports(client, queryString).Result;` this would return the list, which can be passed again to the next method.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of follow up. All edits recommended worked. Thank you so much!